# Spring @Query Remove Quote

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to use a table name in spring query,
but when I execute it I got this following error:

```
"could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"
```

Because spring add automatically quote " when param is a String param ..

```
@Query(value = "desc :name", nativeQuery = true)
List<RepositoryColumn> getColumnFromRepository(@Param("name") String name);
```

In other case I want `"desc table_name"` and not `"desc 'table_Name'"`

Any idea?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring but with how parameter substitution works with JDBC. You cannot use parameter binding for these kind of queries.

Comment: You can create a procedure which will `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE 
     table_name = :name
```

Try the same another way. Instead of `*` you can choose necessary columns

Comment: Thanks ! it's work, but now How can I get the equivalent of a `Select * FROM table_name`

Comment: It is not possible. Using table names as parameters is not supported.