# How do I pass a String parameter into @Query without apostrophes

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

What I need is to pass the mysql schema as a parameter into the @Query, as the example shows:

```
@Query
(value = " SELECT id, name FROM " + schema + ".constructions "
,nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> findAllConstructions(String schema);
```

but this code doesn't work because "schema cannot be resolved to a variable".

The problem is that when I try to pass the parameter correctly, like this:

```
@Query
(value = " SELECT id, name FROM ?.constructions "
,nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> findAllConstructions(String schema);
```

or this:

```
@Query
(value = " SELECT id, name FROM :schema .constructions "
,nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> findAllConstructions(@Param("schema") String schema);
```

the SQL generated has syntax errors, because the FROM clause looks like this:

```
FROM 'db_schema'.constructions
```

when it should be:

```
FROM db_schema.constructions
```

Could anyone help me?

---

**EDIT 1**: I couldn't find any way (in MySQL) to SELECT a specific schema name as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375370/spring-query-remove-quote) suggests for table names.

**EDIT 2**: I solved my issue by creating an alternative connection and setting a statement like this:

```
ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(" SELECT id, name FROM " 
+ schema + ".constructions ");
```

I'll leave the question open because my solution doesn't really answer the question, so if anyone finds an answer for the question, it's still open.

Comment: Where is `schema` coming from?

Comment: @nabster "listConstructions = repository.findAllConstructions(schema);"

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375370/spring-query-remove-quote) should help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @Query Remove Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375370/spring-query-remove-quote)

Comment: @NicholasK Thanks for the suggestion but I believe it's not a duplicate, because my parameter is the schema name, not the table name, and I cannot SELECT the schema name the same way this answer demonstrates for the table name (updated the question to explain this)

Answer (score 0):

try with expression language

```
@Query(value = " SELECT id, name FROM #{#schema}.constructions " ,nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it's also giving me an error: "Parameter with that position [1] did not exist"